# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{99}\sin(n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, contest-math

I'm looking for a trick, or a quick way to evaluate the sum $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{99}\sin(n)}$. I was thinking of applying a sum to product formula, but that doesn't seem to help the situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**: compute $\sum_{n=0}^{99} (\cos(n) + i\sin(n))$.

Comment: Wait, I might be going the wrong way with this method. Is there any easy trick to compute the sum of $e^{ni}$?

Comment: @recursiverecursion: maybe if you write it $\sum_n q^n$ with $q = e^i$?

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

As in other people's answers, you can do this by complex methods.  However if (as suggested by the algebra-precalculus tag) you have not yet met complex numbers...

Let $S$ be the sum.  Using a "products to sums" formula,
$$\eqalign{(2\sin{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})S
  &=\sum_{n=1}^{99}2\sin n\sin{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}\cr
  &=\sum_{n=1}^{99}\bigl(\cos(n-{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})-\cos(n+{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})\bigr)\cr
  &=(\cos{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}+\cos(1{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})+\cdots
    +\cos(98{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}))\cr
  &\qquad\qquad{}-(\cos(1{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})+\cdots
    +\cos(98{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})+\cos(99{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}))\cr
  &=\cos{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}-\cos(99{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})\cr}$$
and so
$$S=\frac{\cos{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}-\cos(99{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}})}{2\sin{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}}\ .$$

**Comment**.  For alternative answers you can follow the same basic idea starting with $(2\sin1)S$, $(2\cos1)S$ etc.

Comment: I have met complex numbers, though I didn't think to use them. Thank you for your answer, though, and I'm glad to know there's more than one way to solve this problem!

Comment: Sneaky... ${}{}$