# Mathematical induction, sum of sines

Tags: trigonometry, induction

> Prove that
> $$\sin\theta+\sin2\theta+\sin3\theta+\cdots+\sin n\theta=\frac{\sin\frac{(n+1)\theta}2\sin\frac{n\theta}2}{\sin\frac\theta2},n\ge1,n\in\mathbb Z.$$

I have solved the base case $n = 1$ and prepared the assumption $n = k$. After I substitute the assumption into the induction step at $n = k+1$ I get lost, as I don't know how to successfully manipulate the numerator into the RHS. Any hints?

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked & answered on this website before.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267244/sum-of-series-sin-theta-sin-2-theta-sin-3-theta-dots and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297452/sines-and-cosines-of-angles-in-arithmetic-progression and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831159/evaluating-sum-n-199-sinn and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349466/calculating-sum-k-0n-sink-theta and probably many, many others.

Comment: Yeah thank you I was looking for it too but I couldn't find an already asked version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin(k\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349466/calculating-sum-k-0n-sink-theta)

Comment: I dont really understand these answers since I haven't done complex numbers yet. Ive posted what I have tried so far as an answer: would you be able to have a look?

Comment: I dont really understand these answers since I haven't done complex numbers yet. Ive posted what I have tried so far as an answer: would you be able to have a look?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is what I have done so far. I cant think of a way to manipulate the LHS into the RHS

Comment: In the comments of my hint, I have tried to explain how it completes this proof.

Answer (score 0):

**BIG HINT**

(Warning: I've written the entire inductive step, just cryptically)

$$\sin{0.5(n+2)}\theta\sin{0.5(n+1)\theta}-\sin{0.5(n+1)}\theta\sin{0.5n\theta}$$

$$=\sin{0.5(n+1)\theta}(\sin{0.5(n+2)}\theta-\sin{0.5n\theta})$$

$$=2\sin{0.5(n+1)\theta}\cos{\frac{0.5(n+2)\theta+0.5n\theta}{2}}\sin{\frac{0.5(n+2)\theta-0.5n\theta}{2}}$$

$$=2\sin{0.5(n+1)\theta}\cos{0.5(n+1)\theta}\sin{0.5\theta}$$

$$=\sin(n+1)\theta \sin{0.5\theta}$$

Comment: ??? Where do we get the (n+2) if we are assuming n = k+1 (or just n => n+1)

Comment: I posted my attempt as an answer - would you be able to have a look?

Comment: @user71207 to understand what I have done in my hint, equate the first line with last line. Then add $\sin{0.5(n+1)\theta\sin{0.5n\theta}}$ to both sides and divide by $\sin{0.5\theta}$. Hopefully you will see then that I have shown exactly the algebra you need to complete your proof.